# Out of memory and Time out in Mysql Query which have join and Union All statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables item and items_sellers, each item can be available in more than one seller.

Here I get ItemId's, sellerId's mapping from another means, now I need details of all those items. I get at least 5000 key(sellerId) value(itemId) pairs, by using this map I need to get the details from those two tables.

To get the results Here I used below query:

```
SELECT 
    table1.column1, 
    table1.column2, 
    table1.column3, 
    table2.column1, 
    table2.column2 
FROM 
    item as table1 
        INNER JOIN ( 
            select 
                key1 as ITEMID, 
                value1 as SELLERID 
            UNION ALL 
            select 
                key2, 
                value2  
            UNION ALL 
            select 
                key3 , 
                value3  
            UNION ALL 
            select 
                key4 , 
                value4 
            UNION ALL
            // ....5000 key value
            pairs
            ) as KEY_VALUE 
            ON table1.item_id = KEY_VALUE.ITEMID 
        INNER JOIN 
            item_sellers as table2 
            ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id 
            AND table2.seller_id = KEY_VALUE.SELLERID
WHERE table1.active = 1
```

This query runs perfectly alright for 3000 - 4000 UNION ALL statements, but giving error i.e. out of memory exception / query time out exception for 5000+ key value pairs i.e. 5000+ UNION ALL statements.

Is there any problem in this query ? If so please through some light on it ?

Is there any way to optimize this query ?

PS: When I put all 5000 key value pairs in this query, query characters becoming 209950 characters ? Is there any character limit for query ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this query? It looks very bad and should be rewritten but I don't know what it should do in first place.

Comment: I need the item and seller information, all I have is bunch of item Ids and seller Ids and their mapping, i.e. bunch of key value pairs map. Could you please suggest something how to rewrite the query ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your subquery is missing the `from` clause.

```
select 
    key1 as ITEMID, 
    value1 as SELLERID 
UNION ALL 
select 
    key2, 
    value2  
UNION ALL 
// and so on...
```

How is it even working at all? It looks like the database is (surprisingly) getting past this and then simply doing a cartesian on the set of data - which is causing memory to spike to the point where it can't cope.

You should try:

```
select 
    key1 as ITEMID, 
    value1 as SELLERID 
from
    yourTableName
UNION ALL 
select 
    key2, 
    value2
from
    yourTableName
Union all // etc etc
```

Having said that, why don't you join to the subquery that contains a where clause to get the rows you need - or use a lookup table between them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't get the key1, value1 and key2, value2 from any table, I get it from another business logic, before I run this query I will be having it in a map, So I am forming a union all query without from clause.

Comment: @Ranjith Although I posted an answer I think complies with your strategy I guess the business logic you refer to gets its data from some database. It that is true then why not transfer the business logic to sql?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and insert into it.

```
create temporary table mytable (itemid integer, sellerid integer);
insert into mytable (itemid, sellerid) values
(1,2),(2,10)
;
SELECT 
    table1.column1, 
    table1.column2, 
    table1.column3, 
    table2.column1, 
    table2.column2 
FROM 
    item as table1 
        INNER JOIN mytable as KEY_VALUE 
            ON table1.item_id = KEY_VALUE.ITEMID 
        INNER JOIN 
            item_sellers as table2 
            ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id 
            AND table2.seller_id = KEY_VALUE.SELLERID
WHERE table1.active = 1
;
drop table mytable;
```

The sql string lenght will be much smaller. Drop it at the end.